# Using WOLA in Liberty WebApp to access CICS

Tags: java, websphere-liberty, cics, zos-connect-ee

Trying to use WOLA direct from a webapp in Liberty to CICS. Using same CICS region successfully with z/OS Connect V2 (zCEE). With Liberty, I have configured:

```
 <featureManager>
     <feature>servlet-3.1</feature>
     <feature>jndi-1.0</feature>
     <feature>jaxrs-1.1</feature>
     <feature>zosLocalAdapters-1.0</feature>
 </featureManager>
```

and

```
 <!-- WOLA group to which others register -->
 <zosLocalAdapters wolaGroup="GROUP" wolaName2="LIBRTOLA" wolaName3="WOLA3" />
 <connectionFactory id="wolaCF" jndiName="eis/ola">
     <properties.ola RegisterName=CICSMLAW/>
 </connectionFactory>
 <resourceAdapter location="/usr/lpp/IBM/zosconnect/v2r0/wlp/lib/ola.rar"/>
```

In the messages.log, I see good and bad items there:

CWWKB0103I: Authorized service group WOLA is available The WebSphere Optimized Local Adapter channel registered with the Liberty profile server using the following name: GROUP LIBRTOLA WOLA3

and the bad:

com.ibm.ws.app.manager.AppMessageHelper E CWWKZ0013E: It is not possible to start two applications called ola.

So the failure on registration: Requestlgth: 97
Requestparms data 1: BBOC START_SRVR RGN=CICSMLA DGN=GROUP NDN=LIBRTOLA
Requestparms data 2: SVN=WOLA3 SVC= MNC=1 MXC=10 TXN=N SEC=N REU=N
Requestparms data 3:
Processing a START SERVER request.
Starting WAS adapters Server task ...
Server transaction id will be: BBO$
Link transaction defaults to: BBO#
Service name will be:
Trace TDQ: BBOQ
Processing a REGISTER API request.
Register name: CICSMLA string len: 7
WAS Daemon: GROUP WAS Node: LIBRTOLA WAS Server: WOLA3
Min. connections: 1
Max. connections: 10
Transactional: N string len: 1
Security propagation: N string len: 1
Invoking OLA Register API for CICSMLA .
on with the Liberty profile server was not successful. The return code is 8, and the reason code 8.

And the failure in the JNDI call:

```
Context ctx = new InitialContext(); 
ConnectionFactory cf = (com.ibm.ws390.ola.jca.ConnectionFactoryImpl)ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/eis/ola");
```

Results in error:

```
[err] javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: java:comp/env/eis/ola
[err] at com.ibm.ws.jndi.url.contexts.javacolon.internal.JavaURLContext.lookup(JavaURLContext.java:356) [err] at [internal classes]
[err] at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:428)
[err] at com.ibm.ctl.bank.impls.CTLBankWolaImpl.(CTLBankWolaImpl.java:51)
[err] at com.ibm.ctl.bank.web.OLTPBankRest.setImpl(OLTPBankRest.java:235)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a lot going on here.

I'm not sure why you're starting ola.rar from the z/OS Connect v2 product, inside of a Liberty server.  The zosLocalAdapters-1.0 feature already loads the ola.rar that ships with Liberty.  You should remove the  configuration from server.xml.  That should resolve the CWWKZ0013E error.

You should see two CWWKB0103I messages in messages.log, one for WOLA (which you included) and one for CLIENT.WOLA.  Please be sure you see both.  It's possible you're on a very old version of Liberty that doesn't print the second CWWKB0103I message, so if this is true, please disregard that part.

I don't think you would have gotten this far without finding the WOLA configuration instructions for the Liberty server in the knowledge center, but here they are for other's benefits:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/was_beta_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twlp_dat_enableconnector.html

OK next, I can't see your application to know whether you've got a resource-reference to a connection factory configured.  I assume you do because you're doing a java:comp/env lookup.  You do not need to cast to com.ibm.ws390.ola.jca.ConnectionFactoryImpl, and actually I highly recommend removing that since that is an internal class and subject to change at any time.  It may be that the application class loader doesn't have access to that class, and that may be part of the problem.

Finally, you have a problem in CICS starting the link server.  You are getting RC=8 RSN=8.  A list of services and return/reason codes can be found here:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/was_beta_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/rwlp_dat_olaapis.html

An 8/8 on BBOA1REG (register) indicates the register token is already in use.  Basically, the RGN= name you picked is already in use.  Are you sure there isn't a PLTPI transaction or something else in the CICS region that is already registered with that name?  Perhaps try a different name just to see if it works, and if it does, maybe try BBOC LIST_SRVR to see what it is?  It's difficult to say how it's getting started without knowing more about your system.

I hope this helps.  Take care!

Comment: The web.xml had not been updated (duh!!) and you are right, the ola was a pre-req of zosLocalAdapters-1.0 ... so both problems are solved.  Thanks for your quick and extremely helpful solution.